# How do you set a Calendar ID when inserting in Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

When using the test API in Google's documentation for [calendar.calendars.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) I always get back `Invalid resource id value.` as a response when setting the request like this

```
{
    "summary": "Events",
    "description": "This is where you will keep your events",
    "id": "test.events"
}
```

The documentation says that the `id` can be any string as long as it doesn't have two consecutive dots and it is longer than 0 and shorter than 101.

What am I doing wrong? I would like to be able to set the `id` so I don't have to store the id that has random characters in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the calendar ID Google Assignes it a Calendar id.

I would assume a Calendar IDs is a primary key and there for must be unique. Google cant allow you to insert your own because then they would have to assume that every programmer bothered to check first that they didn't have one with that ID already.

Comment: Yes it is. I linked to it in my post actually as calendar.calendars.insert. Location actually isn't required because if I just make the request with only summary, it works. I thought for sure that you could set the id. It's annoying that you have to save the id yourself.

Comment: Hmm your right I miss read the documentation I will remove that part of the answer.

Comment: Downvoted because, as you realised, the answer is about the calendar id and the OP was asking about the event id.