# Can't do setId() when insert calendar (calendar api for java)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api

I can't do `setId()` when insert a calendar (Calendar api for java).

i recived a errors:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
>   Bad Request {   "code": 400,   "errors": [
>       {
>         "domain": "global",
>         "message": "Invalid resource id value.",
>         "reason": "invalid"
>       }   ],   "message": "Invalid resource id value." }

My code:

```
private fun insertCalendar(){
    object : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            val calendar = com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar()
                    .setSummary("Lich hoc ictu")
                    .setDescription("Lich hoc ictu")
                    .setTimeZone("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
                    .setId("calendarictu@group.calendar.google.com")
            service.Calendars().insert(calendar).execute()
            runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }.start()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799150/8713068

So basically you cannot set your own ID, Google does it for you.

There you have something about retrieving Calendars ID : 
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars

Comment: Uhm! Other, I need get a calendar id, any way do it?

Comment: In the second link there is annotation :
`id - string - Identifier of the calendar. To retrieve IDs call the calendarList.list() method.`
but I'm not sure if thats a correct method

Comment: Thank you! I used calendarList.list(), it don't need to set custom calendar id